# css order property adding ghost spacing on top with flex - trying to imitate float right

Tags: css, flexbox

I am essentially trying to imitate `float: right` with images in a row and I am getting a mysterious space above the parent item when I do it. I am using flexbox in the elements and I tried to achieve the `float: right` type functionality by using the `order: 2` property. Here is a screenshot: [image]

A live sample of the app can here: `removed link, because in development`, forgive the long load times. Just click "play"

Comment: Give flex to parent div like 
`app-game.ng-star-inserted {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}`

Comment: this worked as well, but can't mark it as the correct answer, thank you!

Comment: In general `float` *really* does not play well with flexbox, choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two `app-team` components inside `app-game` component make app-game as a flex container so `app-team` components will be flex items.

```
.app-game-class {
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
}
```